# Parallel tests with Gherkin, Specflow and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest, specflow, gherkin

I'm setting up automated acceptance tests for an Asp.Net MVC project using Gherkin scenarios, Specflow steps and Selenium remote webdriver. The aim is to run the tests from Jenkins in parallel on multiple nodes using the selenium server hub.

At the moment I'm trying to get them to run in parallel locally and having some difficulties. Is it even possible to run those tests in parallel with the Gherkin/Specflow setup or does the fact the Gherkin scenarios re-use the same Specflow steps for similar scenarios make it impossible to run them concurrently ?

If it's not impossible how exactly can it be done ? And if it is impossible what else could be done to speed up the testing process ?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with

> the fact the Gherkin scenarios re-use the same Specflow steps for similar scenarios make it impossible to run them concurrently

It's totally possible to run your `MSTest` cases [in parallel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpu-core-machine.aspx). As far as I'm aware the max number of hung tests shouldn't exceed *5*. However I've used custom tool for this purpose, spawning every test in a separate thread, it's easy achievable with [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Maybe I have it set up wrong then. When I run them individually or together but without parallel execution they run fine. When I enable parallel execution I run into problems. For example if I run two scenarios to test different links load their respective pages, the second one will fail as it gets the result of the first. Maybe they are trying to run parallel on the same driver instance or something.

Comment: My guess is that you're mixing the  'IWebDriver' instance. Every driver comunicates with single corresponding browser instance via its session id. Look at your design again :)

Comment: I have a scenario outline to run 5 similar tests. I have a BeforeScenario method to create a new RemoteWebDriver and an AfterScenario to tear it down. When I run more than one test with parallel execution the AfterScenario method to quit the driver kills the remaining tests. How do I create a new driver for each run of the scenario ?

Comment: The design from BDD perspective sounds about right, but "AfterScenario method to quit the driver kills the remaining tests." tells me maybe you are passing the same driver instance between MSTest methods, so which test finishes first kills it. Can you try and add this attribute to your *BeforeScenario* method - `[TestInitialize]`.

Comment: There seems to be two different results. Firstly on some runs, one throws an exception right away of "Item with same key already added". The second result is an "Object reference not set to instance of an object" error. I looks like there is only ever one instance of the driver, as soon as a second test runs the first browser stops. If I run two tests the second one to run will pass as it hijacks the driver from the first. If I run 3+ tests as soon as one test quits no more will run or quit. The "Item with same key" I'd assume is a reference to the driver ?

Comment: Everything points that most likely, you have model which contains the same property (driver) twice. Perhaps you are using new to hide the base property.

Comment: I came across that answer on another question, as you said it does point to that but I don't see where the driver is being used twice unless each test tries to create the same driver. In which case how do I ensure each run of the scenario creates a unique driver ?

Comment: It's a matter of design. Avoid inheritance of the driver in tests where possible. Maybe when your child tests get the Driver property from the base - this issue happens. Double check how you instantiate the derived classes.

Comment: The driver isn't inherited. It's created in the setup.

Comment: What I meant was if you pass this driver in some hierarchically structured Page objects or Test ones.

Comment: I added some code, may that might make things a bit clearer.

Comment: Looks ok to me -  I can't find any flaws in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the selenium grid to do this, and I would recommend putting the grid on another computer or virtual machine if you can.

You can run the same test on multiple browsers using a combination of 1) the task parallel library and 2) the dynamic object class. I've written about the specifics here http://blog.dmbcllc.com/running-selenium-in-parallel-with-any-net-unit-testing-tool/